# Приоритет операций и iostream

Tags: c++, c

Есть стек, реализованный на массиве. Почему при выполнении данного кода получаем в результате "12", если же написать "cout" в разных строках то получаем "21"? Буду очень благодарен за объяснение или статью где можно почитать об этом.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct stack
{
    int size = 0;
    int st[1024];
};
void push(stack &st, int data)
{
   if(st.size >= 1024)
      cout<< "Stack Overflow!\n";
   else
   {
      st.st[st.size] = data;st.size++;
   }
}
int pop(stack &st)
{
    if(st.size>=0)
    {
        --st.size;
        int data = st.st[st.size];
        return data;
    }
    else cout<< "Stack Underflow!\n";
}

int main()
{
   stack mainstack;
   push(mainstack, 1);
   push(mainstack, 2);
   cout<< pop(mainstack)<<pop(mainstack);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Очень странно. Должно быть по идее в обеих случая 21. Дайте подумать...

Comment: http://ideone.com/9EAx9J та же фигня :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В данном случае порядок вызова функций `pop()` не определён, они не вызываются слева-направо, а так как решит компилятор.
Точно так же, как и в выражении
`f() + g()`
что вызовется `f()` перед `g()` или наоборот в стандарте не говорится - всё решается компилятором.
[Порядок вычисления](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)

Comment: Хм, кажется, вы правы.